# How to ensure @Entity exists in @Async methods?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, asynchronous

I want to create an entity, and within the transaction trigger an `@Async` method to perform some changes on the same entity. The changes should also be persisted async.

Problem: as I have to fire the async method within the transaction, I could use the autogenerated `@Id` from the entity. BUT the async method then would have to first fetch the entity by that Id, and most often this does not exist yet.

Only if I put some `Thread.sleep()` as first statement inside the async method, it can mostly be ensured that the entity has been persisted by the outer transaction.

But that solution is not very nice. Question: how can I ensure inside the async method that it should wait for the entity to exist in DB?

```
@Service
public class OuterService {
    @Service
    private SyncService service;

    @Transactional
    public void process() {
        service.mySyncMethod();
        //etc
    }
}

@Service
public class SyncService {
    @Transactional
    public void mySnycMethod() {
        Entity entity = new MyEntity();
        //fill entity
        dao.save(entity);
        asyncService.performLongRunningTask(entity.getId());
    }
}

@Service
public class AsycnService {
    @Async
    @Transactional
    public voi performLongRunningTask(Long id) {
        //problem: is mostly == null because this is executed before the outer transaction completes
        //only works if I put like Thread.sleep(5000) in between. but how can I really ensure the entity exists before executing this async lookup?
        MyEntity entity = dao.findOne(id);

        //perform long running task
        //change some fields in entity accordingly
        dao.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your `OuterService` not transactional, and move the call to the `AsyncService.performLongRunningTask` to that. That ensures the transaction has finished and the entity is in the database.

Comment: Would it make sense then to also pass the detached entity instead of the id, to save the dao lookup in the async method?

Comment: You would still need to reattach it as the session isn't valid anymore. I would simply pass the ID.

Comment: OK thanks. Anyways probably I cannot make `OuterService` not transactional as there is much logic (also database/dao calls that must participate in the tx) before and behind that specifc call that causes the problems...

Comment: Then wrap all those calls in a transaction and not the call to the async stuff. You can move it to a different class which you can annotate transactional. You just have to make sure the transaction is committed before calling your async method. Figure out a way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I finally implemented is to use Spring application events through `ApplicationEvent`, `ApplicationEventPublisher` and `@ApplicationEventListener` with `phase = AFTER_COMMIT`.
Then your async method will be invoked after transaction and entity persistence.

```
public class MyEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private Long entityId;
    
    // constructor and getter
    ...
}

@Service
public class SyncService {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationEventPublisher pub;

    @Transactional
    public void mySyncMethod() {
        Entity entity = new MyEntity();
        //fill entity
        dao.save(entity);
        pub.publishEvent(new MyEvent(entity.getId()));
    }
}

@Service
public class AsyncService {
    @Async
    @Transactional
    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = AFTER_COMMIT)
    public void performLongRunningTask(MyEvent event) {
        MyEntity entity = dao.findOne(event.getEntityId());

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could register a hook on transaction commit using the `TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization()` and implementing the `afterCommit()` method.

```
@Transactional
public void mySnycMethod() {
    Entity entity = new MyEntity();
    // fill entity
    dao.save(entity);
    // performLongRunningTask will start after the transaction has been
    // commited
    TransactionSynchronizationManager
            .registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void afterCommit() {
                    asyncService.performLongRunningTask(entity.getId());
                }
            });

}
```

But note what the Javadocs say about using the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` in your application:

> To be used by resource management code but not by typical application
>   code

Comment: Well, it is a quite old post but I am facing the same problem. The main method register in DB an action that is long to process and delegate to an @Async method the processing. In 2020 there is no other solution than your "hack" @Ruben ? (I mean JMS is perfeclty suited for this case but a solution with `@Async` ?)

Comment: You can call one method after the other, but have to make sure that the first one has finished the transaction before calling the async one. e.g. by. wrapping the sync method with a @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: @Ruben Your solution does not work